# Angular 8 - Inject class to indicate table sort direction

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm attempting to inject a class into the header of my table. The table columns can be sorted, descending and ascending. I want the header class to change, depending on direction of the column. A "default" class is also injected when the column is not actively being sorted.

There are a few things I should note in my component. `sortDirection$ = this.sortedColumn$.pipe()` is where I'm pulling the sort direction into a variable. I'm storing it in the `directionColumn` variable. `sortOn()` is called when one of the table headers is clicked. That is also where I'm determining which column is being sorted with the `activeColumn` variable. You can see `getClass()` is where I'm pulling in both of these variables to determine 1) whether or not a column is being sorted, and 2) which direction it is being sorted.

```
import { NavbarService } from './../navbar/navbar.service';
import { LiveUpdatesService } from './live-updates.service';
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { sortByColumn } from './../utilities/array.functions';
import { combineLatest, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-live-updates',
  templateUrl: './live-updates.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sass/live-updates.component.scss']
})
export class LiveUpdatesComponent implements OnInit{
  stocks$: Observable<any[]>;
  sortedColumn$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  activeColumn: string;
  directionColumn: string;

  sortDirection$ = this.sortedColumn$.pipe(
    scan<string, {col: string, dir: string}>((sort, val) => {
      this.directionColumn = sort.dir;
      console.log(sort.dir);
      return sort.col === val
        ? { col: val, dir: sort.dir === 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc' }
        : { col: val, dir: 'desc' };
    }, {dir: 'desc', col: ''})
  )


  constructor(private updatesService: LiveUpdatesService, public nav: NavbarService, private cdRef : ChangeDetectorRef) {
    // combine observables, use map operator to sort
    this.stocks$ = combineLatest(this.updatesService.getStocks(), this.sortDirection$).pipe(
      map(([list, sort]) => !sort.col ? list : sortByColumn(list, sort.col, sort.dir))
    );
  }
  sortOn(column: string) {
    this.activeColumn = column;
    this.sortedColumn$.next(column);
  }

  getClass(columnID: string) {
    if (this.activeColumn === columnID && this.directionColumn === "asc"){
      return "asc";
    } else if (this.activeColumn === columnID && this.directionColumn === "desc") {
      return "desc"
    } else {
      return "default";
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.nav.show();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

You can see in my HTML that I'm calling `getClass('activeColumn')` to determine the class. When a column is not actively being sorted, `getClass()` returns "default." Once the header is clicked, it either returns "asc" or "desc". The HTML for the table:

```
<table class="stock-updates">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ticker-fixed">Listing</th>
                    <th>
                        <a (click)="sortOn('price')" [ngClass]="getClass('price')">Ask Price</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a (click)="sortOn('zestimate')" [ngClass]="getClass('zestimate')">Zes.</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a (click)="sortOn('tax_diff')" [ngClass]="getClass('tax_diff')">Tax Difference</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a (click)="sortOn('zes_diff')" [ngClass]="getClass('zes_diff')">Zes. Difference</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a (click)="sortOn('cash_on_cash')" [ngClass]="getClass('cash_on_cash')">Cash on Cash</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a (click)="sortOn('rent_zestimate')" [ngClass]="getClass('rent_zestimate')">Rent Zes.</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a (click)="sortOn('rent_to_val')" [ngClass]="getClass('rent_to_val')">Rent to Val.</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a (click)="sortOn('sqft')" [ngClass]="getClass('sqft')">SqFt</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a (click)="sortOn('status_text')" [ngClass]="getClass('status_text')">Status</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a (click)="sortOn('search_name')" [ngClass]="getClass('search_name')">Query</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let s of ((stocks$ | async) | search:'address':query)">
                    <td class="ticker-fixed">
                        <a target="_blank" href="{{s.detail_url}}"><img src="./assets/img/external-link-solid.svg" alt="Zillow Listing"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ s.price | currency:'USD':'symbol-narrow':"1.0-2" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ s.zestimate | currency:'USD':'symbol-narrow':"1.0-2" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ s.tax_diff | currency:'USD':'symbol-narrow':"1.0-2" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ s.zes_diff | currency:'USD':'symbol-narrow':"1.0-2" }}</td> 
                    <td>{{ s.cash_on_cash | percent }}</td>
                    <td>{{ s.rent_zestimate | currency:'USD':'symbol-narrow':"1.0-2" }}</td>                  
                    <td>{{ s.rent_to_val | percent }}</td>
                    <td>{{ s.sqft }}</td>
                    <td>{{ s.status_text }}</td>
                    <td>{{ s.search_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ s.address }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The function that handles the sorting:

```
export function sortByColumn(list: any[] | undefined, column:string, direction = 'asc'): any[] {
  let sortedArray = (list || []).sort((a,b)=>{
    if(a[column] > b[column]){
      return 1;
    }
    if(a[column] < b[column]){
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  })
return (direction === 'asc') ? sortedArray : sortedArray.reverse();
}
```

My problem is that my classes are not being injected accurately. For example, when I begin clicking around on different headers, the classes are injected as I'd suspect, but eventually, they get jumbled around. One header may accurately show `.asc` and be sorting in ascending order, but after clicking between different headers and then coming back to that header, it may show `.desc` and be sorting in ascending order.

Notice how the arrow icon has changed in these screenshots, while the sort direction has not. Just to confirm, the sorting functionality is working fine. It is only the injection of classes that is getting jumbled.
[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? What can I change so that the classes accurate reflect the direction of the sorting?

Comment: The problem is that you need to maintain the states of the direction for all your columns. When you click around on the headers and come back to the other header you are picking the state of the previous column that you clicked on.

Comment: @Kellen can you set up a minimal reproducible (stackblitz) example?

Comment: @joe, I will try! May be by the end of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the issue you are facing and fixed it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-material-eejy9s). I did find 2 issues with the code.

1. Issue with the sorting logic: You have following code in your helper function `return (direction === 'asc') ? sortedArray : sortedArray.reverse();` which would reverse resulting array irrespective of the content in the column when in descending order, which I fixed by updating logic to:

```js
export function sortByColumn(list: any[] | undefined, column:string, direction = 'asc'): any[] {
  const isAscending = direction === 'asc';
  const sortedArray = (list || []).sort((a,b)=>{
    if(a[column] > b[column]){
      return isAscending ? 1 : -1;
    }
    if(a[column] < b[column]){
      return isAscending ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  return sortedArray;
}
```

2. Second thing I fixed is in the logic which was updating `directionColumn` variable. You were updating it based on accumulated value `this.directionColumn = sort.dir;` as opposed to new value, due to which your `directionColumn` would be different than direction data is sorted in.

```js
sortDirection$ = this.sortedColumn$.pipe(
  scan<string, {col: string, dir: string}>((sort, val) => {
    const retVal = sort.col === val
      ? { col: val, dir: sort.dir === 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc' }
      : { col: val, dir: 'desc' };
    this.directionColumn = retVal.dir;      
    return retVal;
  }, {dir: 'desc', col: ''})
)
```

Comment: Magic! That did it. Thank you for your help on this.